# Call LaTeX from Python Django

Tags: python, django, subprocess, xelatex

Within django, I am using jinja2 to render a template into a .tex file. I then need to call 'xelatex' on this .tex file, and save the output as a django File object.

I've got as far as this:

```
tex_file = render_to_string("foo.tex", context)
```

If I save `tex_file` to a file, and run xelatex on it, I get the expected output, so it works up until this point.

I then tried something like this:

```
subprocess.run(["xelatex", tex_file], capture_output=True])
```

The problem is that I don't actually want to capture xelatex's output to STDOUT. I want to capture the output.pdf file that it generates.

I know that I could just have xelatex save this file to /tmp/, and then have python open it and deal with it, but this seems slow and messy. Is there any way of getting subprocess to actually return the output:

```
output = subprocess.run(["xelatex", tex_file], capture_output=True])
self.file = file
```

Comment: `output.stdout` gives you what was captured on stdout, but that assumes that xelatex is outputting the pdf on stdout, which I don't know if it can. You need to look at xelatex's man page.

Comment: @dirkgroten It can't. Is there another way to do this? I could try a temporary file system, and handle it using that?

Comment: then the only way is to make it write to a file and then read that file in python, as you described. A bit slower, but with most cloud servers using SSDs these days, still pretty fast.

Comment: @dirkgroten Ok, thanks. I'll do it in a ram based filesystem, so it should be faster